# opencart admin not working after change http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, opencart

I am new in opencart. I want to enable `SSL` in opencart.
So that I tried to change following file.

`config.php` file changes

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');
```

`admin/config.php` file changes

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/');
```

`system/library/url.php` file change *(line : 16)*

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = true)
```

`.htaccess` put changes following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Admin panel change `Setting > Server > Use SSL set **yes**'

After above changes I can not login admin panel does not display any error message.

Answer (score 2):

Editing your config.php file in root and in admin folder to point to the https urls and .htaccess file.

Also in the system/config directory

respectively 2 files:

admin.php (for admin backend)

find

```
$_['site_ssl']         = false;
```

change it to

```
$_['site_ssl']         = true;
```

same at the file catalog.php (for frontend)

Answer (score 0):

You've missed https for the admin url. 
Change the below values in your `admin/config.php`

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://example.com/');
```

to

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/');
```

Comment: is everything fine for the frontend pages?

Comment: Yes but admin login not possible

Comment: Does the admin login page get displayed and its form action has https url ? Also let us know why did you change : `system/library/url.php file change (line : 16)`.

Comment: thank you, for your last suggestion. login form action has not https url but i tyried to replace manually after that its work. How can i change from action url ?
I got solution from somewhere thats why i tried to change in `url.php`.

Comment: try to change all the config file urls to https for both admin and frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111616/discussion-between-sankar-v-and-learning-phase).

Comment: I can not save every setting in Admin Panel after all changes.

Answer (score 0):

go to root folder click system  and then go to config , highlight admin.php,and edit it...make sure site ssl is true

Answer (score 0):

To make the entire site SSL which is now the trend (like on amazon.co.uk etc) and gives a little SEO boost. I had to make the http_server setting to be https. Along with this too:

https for OpenCart 1.5

Switch on in Settings/System/Server
Check admin/config.pgp and config.php have correct SSL url set

Setting the http_server setting in config.php - usually and should be http. When set to https that seems to sort it.

So in config.php I now have

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

So now when I "view source" when the page is in http and search for any refs to http:// I get no returns.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix this problem. in system/library/url.php

change

```
if ($connection ==  'NONSSL') {
    $url = $this->url;  
} else {
    $url = $this->ssl;  
}
```

to

```
$url = $this->ssl;
```

This force all link to use https

Answer (score 0):

Create new .htaccess file in admin page with only this code in it:

```
RewriteBase /
```